# How can I add additional to a dynamically imported module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, tinymce

So I use TinyMce which would look like this with ES6:

```
// Import TinyMCE
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';

// Default icons are required for TinyMCE 5.3 or above
import 'tinymce/icons/default';

// A theme is also required
import 'tinymce/themes/silver';

// Any plugins you want to use has to be imported
import 'tinymce/plugins/paste';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';

// Initialize the app
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tiny',
  plugins: ['paste', 'link']
});
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
import(/!* webpackChunkName: "tinymce" *!/ 'tinymce/tinymce').then(tinymce => {
  tinymce.default.init({
  selector: '#tiny',
  plugins: ['paste', 'link']
  });
})
```

but I don't really know how to add the icons, themes and plugins

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a cleaner approach, but what about statically import them in an index.js, for ex, and then destructing the import, like this:

```
import('./index.js')
.then(({export1, export2}) => {
    ···
});
```